# Why can we only assign a basic and dynamic PIP to a virtual network gateway on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

As the title says. Why can we only assign a public IP address of SKU **basic** and **dynamic** (which is a legacy type and does not support **Availability Zone Scenarios**)?

Doesn't that complicate things e.g. when connecting with on-prem VPN devices?

> You can only assign a dynamic basic public IP address to a VPN gateway

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm

Comment: Why the down-vote? Please leave a comment, so I can improve my question!

Answer (score 0):

There are [multiple Gateway SKUs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-about-vpn-gateway-settings#gwsku) on Azure. In fact, you can use standard static Public IP for gateway SKU VpnGw1AZ, VpnGw2AZ, VpnGw3AZ,VpnGw4AZ,VpnGw5AZ.

[image]